# What's the purpose of "AND AL,0xFF"?

Tags: assembly, bitwise-operators, eflags

I'm reading through a disassembled win32 c++ program and I see quite a few:

```
AND AL,0xFF
```

Is this completely pointless or why would the compiler generate these?

Here is a longer example:

```
movsx   eax, byte ptr [ebx]
shl     eax, 18h
movsx   edx, byte ptr [ebx+1]
shl     edx, 10h
add     eax, edx
movsx   ecx, byte ptr [ebx+2]
shl     ecx, 8
add     eax, ecx
movsx   edx, byte ptr [ebx+3]
add     eax, edx
xor     edx, edx
call    sub_43B55C
mov     ecx, eax
mov     edx, eax
sar     ecx, 10h
and     al, 0FFh      # <----
sar     edx, 8
and     cl, 0FFh      # <----
mov     [esi], cl
and     dl, 0FFh      # <----
mov     [esi+1], dl
mov     [esi+2], al
add     ebx, 4
add     esi, 3
inc     ebp
cmp     ebp, 6
jl      short loc_43B5E4
```

The flags aren't being checked after these operations so that can't be the purpose. After the `AND`, the values in `AL`, `CL`, and `DL` are being moved to `[ESI + n]`.

Comment: Without knowing what came before, it's difficult to say.  Let's suppose though EAX is a pointer and it needs to be aligned on a 16-byte boundary. This would set ZF if true, so the point to the instruction is just to set flag(s). Alternatively, `test al, 0xff` might be used if compiler setup appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The flags aren't being checked. The ANDing seems to be occurring before the bytes are moved to memory. I updated with surrounding code for context.

Comment: Seems really weird. Perhaps this instruction is present for padding or as a marker for hooks.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a poorly optimizing compiler that failed to optimize away the idiom `foo = bar & 0xff`. What program generated this code?

Comment: @fuz : This is the most likely scenario IMHO, as the code looks like some binary/bit-level (re)packing function.

Comment: Borland C + + Builder 6

Comment: I'm not seeing these as "with no purpose at all" since we have values being loaded into EAX and ECX. I mean, why exactly you consider the AL math in this sample as useless just because they don't set flags?

Comment: @DavidBS : yes, but how can an AND of an 8-bit value with `0xFF` modify the value even the slightest?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar, you're right, I didn't realized this in this sample!  Tks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @fuz suggested, this is simply the fault of an optimizer not recognizing `foo & 0xff` as being a no-op in the context in which it was most probably used in the original function.

I compiled the following code snippet with Borland C++ Builder 6 after setting the project's compilation settings to "Release" :

```
unsigned char foobar(int foo) { return (foo >> 16) & 0xff; }
```

This resembles the operations carried out in the disassembly you provided quite closely. We have a 32-bit value which we want to shift a given number of bits and then turn it into a byte value, essentially returning bits 16-23 of the original value as one byte. The input parameter is of type `int` in order to generate a `sar` instruction instead of a `shr` : most probably an `int` was used in the original code as well.

After compiling and disassembling the resulting .obj with [objconv](http://www.agner.org/optimize/objconv.zip) (as I couldn't figure out how to enable assembly listings from within the C++ Builder's IDE), I got this :

```
@foobar$qi PROC NEAR
;  COMDEF @foobar$qi
        push    ebp                                     ; 0000 _ 55
        mov     ebp, esp                                ; 0001 _ 8B. EC
        mov     eax, dword ptr [ebp+8H]                 ; 0003 _ 8B. 45, 08
        sar     eax, 16                                 ; 0006 _ C1. F8, 10
        and     al, 0FFFFFFFFH                          ; 0009 _ 24, FF
        pop     ebp                                     ; 000B _ 5D
        ret                                             ; 000C _ C3
@foobar$qi ENDP
```

As you can see, the redundant `and` is still there. The 32-bit immediate in the disassembly can be disregarded, since the instruction's encoding clearly shows that the immediate in the actual code stream is 8-bit : there are no other valid options with an 8-bit register anyway.

Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 6 seems to be guilty of the same thing, but operates on the whole 32-bit register (thus generating 3 bytes more due to the 32-bit immediate), clearing the upper bits - which is needless, seeing how the return value of the function was explicitly declared to be 8-bit :

```
?foobar@@YAEH@Z PROC NEAR                               ; foobar
; 1    : unsigned char foobar(int foo) { return (foo >> 16) & 0xff; }
  00000 55               push    ebp
  00001 8b ec            mov     ebp, esp
  00003 8b 45 08         mov     eax, DWORD PTR _foo$[ebp]
  00006 c1 f8 10         sar     eax, 16                        ; 00000010H
  00009 25 ff 00 00 00   and     eax, 255               ; 000000ffH
  0000e 5d               pop     ebp
  0000f c3               ret     0
?foobar@@YAEH@Z ENDP                                    ; foobar
```

Meanwhile, [the oldest version of gcc available on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/3Cdz2y) correctly compiles this into what's essentially just a shift, except the natural differences between the listings due to calling conventions.